# Update display in Android

Tags: android

This is what I am doing

```
ProgressBar myProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
fetchData();
mainView();
myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

But the progressbar does not show.
fetchData takes around 5 seconds and while it is running, the progressbar should be shown.
I guess the display is not updated while the App is busy. Is there a way to update the display before I call fetchData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). This will allow you to run `fetchData()` using the `doInBackground(...)` method and post progress using `onProgressUpdate(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the layout file give `android:visibility="visible"` for the `ProgressBar`. And when the content is loaded u set visibity to `invisible`.

Comment: what does fetchdata() method contain?

Comment: did u set setProgress for the ProgressBar? If not do that.